# How to install python3-dev in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

I am trying to install **python3-dev** in Ubuntu 20.04, got the following error:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python3-dev

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3-dev : Depends: python3.8-dev (>= 3.8.2-1~) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

This suggest that I need to install **python3.8-dev** first, so I tried to install that package and it failed with the following error:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python3.8-dev

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3.8-dev : Depends: zlib1g-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Again, I tried to install the package: **zlib1g-dev** and it also failed:

```
$ sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 zlib1g-dev : Depends: zlib1g (= 1:1.2.11.dfsg-2ubuntu1) but 1:1.2.11.dfsg-2ubuntu1.2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Finally, the package **zlib1g** is already installed but it seems that **zlib1g-dev** needs a different version of **zlib1g**. However, it seems that ubuntu 20.04 doesn't have it:

```
$ sudo apt-get install zlib1g=1.2.11.dfsg-2ubuntu1

Reading state information... Done
E: Version '1.2.11.dfsg-2ubuntu1' for 'zlib1g' was not found
```

What can I do at this point?

Comment: Why not just install from source?

Comment: Try `sudo aptitude install <packagename>`, it may fix your problem. Also try `sudo apt-get autoremove`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  ```sudo aptitude install``` works. Through the options provided, I was able to downgrade the ```zlib1g``` package to version ```1:1.2.11.dfsg-2ubuntu1``` and install the ```python3-dev``` package.

Answer (score 4):

before to install this, you have to be root

```
sudo -i
```

then

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev
```